# Add webview in Xamarin gtk form

Tags: webview, xamarin, gtk#

I want to use Webview in Xamarin gtk Form. The problem is that i can't find Webview in toolbox.
Looking at this example i added some code in default MainWindow.cs code.

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using Xamarin.Forms;
 public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
 {

    public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
        WebView webView = new WebView
        {
            Source = new UrlWebViewSource
            {
                Url = "http://blog.xamarin.com/",
            },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        vbox2.Add (webView); //giving error since it webview is not widget.
    }
    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Gtk.Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

I am new to Xamarin and i don't know i can i create a xamarin gtk# tool that can run on OSX and windows.

I also want to fill htmlDocument and invoke click. Is it possible with xamarin gtk# webview